# How to Toggle a var Bool in a @EnvironmentObject var thanks to a Toggle

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Good morning everyone,

I'm trying to create an application for a connected home. 
So I have a light class that has the property of having a @Published var allLights: [Light] as follows:

```swift
struct Light: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var deviceName: String
    var intensity: Int
    // Should I remove the State wrapper ? 
    // Because Toggle only works with @State / Binding var...
    @State var mode: Bool 
}

class Lights: ObservableObject {
    @Published var allLights = [Light]()

    init() // I initialize this array using an API (thanks to SwiftyJSON)
}
```

Thus, in a View I would like to be able to change the different values of my lights (only the mode var for the moment). 
However the Toggle does not change the value of the @State var mode of each light...
Here is the code for the view

```swift
struct LightsCollection: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var lightStore : Lights

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(lightStore.allLights) { light in
                HStack {
                    Text("\(light.id)")
                    Text("\(light.deviceName)")
                    Text("- \(light.intensity)")
                    Text("- " + String(light.mode))
                    Toggle(isOn: light.$mode) {
                        Text(light.mode ? "Switch off" : "Switch on")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've already read a lot of forums but nothing to do... 
Any help will be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have something going with the following (hack included):

First declare Light as a class because a struct will not allow changes to mode:

```
class Light: Identifiable {
var id: Int
var deviceName: String
var intensity: Int
var mode: Bool

init(id: Int, deviceName: String, intensity: Int, mode: Bool) {
    self.id = id
    self.deviceName = deviceName
    self.intensity = intensity
    self.mode = mode
}
}
```

then

```
struct LightsCollection: View {
@EnvironmentObject var lightStore : Lights
@State var refresh = false

var body: some View {
      ForEach(lightStore.allLights) { light in
            HStack {
                Text("\(light.id)")
                Text("\(light.deviceName)")
                Text("- \(light.intensity)")
                Text("- " + String(light.mode))
                Toggle(isOn: Binding(get: {
                    light.mode
                }, set: { newVal in
                    light.mode = newVal
                    self.refresh.toggle()
                })) {
                    Text(light.mode ? "Switch off" : "Switch on").accentColor(self.refresh ? .black : .black)
                }
            }
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude, it works perfectly ! I finally go with an other way, I have created a Button which looks like a Toggle, playing with some ZStack and HStack ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions for your problem, First one will be with `struct` and second with `Class`.

---

### Using Struct

Model Class:

```
struct Light: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var deviceName: String
    var intensity: Int
    // State are used with View  
    var mode: Bool        
}
```

and your View Class will look like below as this is an array of struct so you have to access it with index and change it's value

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(lightStore.allLights.indices) { index in
                HStack {
                    Text("\(self.lightStore.allLights[index].id)")
                    Text("\(self.lightStore.allLights[index].deviceName)")
                    Text("- \(self.lightStore.allLights[index].intensity)")
                    Text("- " + String(self.lightStore.allLights[index].mode))
                    Toggle(isOn: Binding(get: {
                        return self.lightStore.allLights[index].mode
                    }) { (value) in
                        //self.objectWillChange.send()
                        self.lightStore.allLights[index].mode = value
                    }) {
                        Text(self.lightStore.allLights[index].mode ? "Switch off" : "Switch on")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

### Using Class

Model Class:

```
class Light: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    var id: Int
    var deviceName: String
    var intensity: Int
    var mode: Bool

    init(id: Int, deviceName: String, intensity: Int, mode: Bool) {
        self.id = id
        self.deviceName = deviceName
        self.intensity = intensity
        self.mode = mode
    }
}
```

and you View class will be like below

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(lightStore.allLights) { light in
                HStack {
                    Text("\(light.id)")
                    Text("\(light.deviceName)")
                    Text("- \(light.intensity)")
                    Text("- " + String(light.mode))
                    Toggle(isOn: Binding(get: {
                        return light.mode
                    }) { (value) in
                        self.lightStore.objectWillChange.send() // you have to manually tell lightStore object to update
                        light.mode = value
                    }) {
                        Text(light.mode ? "Switch off" : "Switch on")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```